# Unexpected low-beam headlight design in 2012 Kia Rio Hatchback

Tags: headlight, kia, rio

I need to change the passenger-side low-beam headlight bulb for a 2012 Kia Rio Hatchback. After doing some Googling, it appears that most tutorials ([such as this one](https://youtu.be/_tBNEOT7YRs)) expect there to be a wire harness that slides off and a metal clip/brace that holds the bulb in place. However, after removing the cylindrical cap in my 2012 Rio, I saw a completely different structure holding the low-beam bulb in place, as pictured here: [image: This design does not correspond with any 2012 Kia Rio headlight tutorials that I have been able to find.]
The circular plug which holds the bulb in place does not rotate/twist out (presumably because of the teeth at the bottom of it), and the wire harness below the circular plug/teeth does not unscrew out of the way. Has anyone ever encountered a design like this, or found a tutorial that addresses a design like this? Any recommendations are much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!